# Why I cannot get correct class of a custom class through isKindOfClass?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I've created a custom class `AnimalView` which is a subclass of `UIView` containing a `UILabel` and a `UIImageView`.

```
@interface AnimalView : UIView {
    UILabel *nameLabel;
    UIImageView *picture;
}
```

Then I added in several `AnimalView` onto the ViewController.view.  In the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method, I wanted to detect if the touched object is an `AnimalView` or not.  Here is the code for the viewController:

```
@implementation AppViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:...
    [self.view addSubview scrollview];

    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        AnimalView *newAnimal = [[AnimalView alloc] init];
        // customization of newAnimal
        [scrollview addSubview:newAnimal;
    }
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    UIView *hitView = touch.view;
    if ([hitView isKindOfClass:[AnimalView class]]) {
        AnimalView *animal = (AnimalView *)hitView;
        [animal doSomething];
    }
}
```

However, nothing happened when I clicked on the animal.  When I checked the class of `hitView` by `NSLog(@"%@", [hitView class])`, it always shows `UIView` instead of `AnimalView`.  Is it true that the AnimalView changed to a UIView when it is added onto the ViewController?  Is there any way I can get back the original class of a custom class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does an AnimalView have UIView subviews within it?  They might be the ones picking up the touch events.  You could disable the user interaction of those views by inverting the method described by David on all of the subviews of your AnimalView.

Comment: Thanks Brad for reminding. As I was away from my mac, I totally forgot I have one more UIView in the AnimalView. This totally solved my headache. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that AnimalView doesn't have user interaction enabled and is ignoring the touches. Try setting `[myView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];`

Comment: Thanks David. I've already set the userInteractionEnabled property to YES on the AnimalView in its init method. In fact, I got a return of "UIView" when I clicked on them. But what I want is a return of "AnimalView". Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you have subviews in your AnimalView, you can iterate through the superview hierarchy to see if the touch was handled by a subview of your AnimalView by using code like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    UIView *hitView = touch.view;

    AnimalView *animal = nil;
    while (hitView != nil) {
        if ([hitView isKindOfClass:[AnimalView class]]) {
            animal = (AnimalView *) hitView;
            break;
        }
        hitView = [hitView superview];
    }

    if (animal) {
        [animal doSomething];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But turn out it was a stupid mistake by myself. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Not a problem! I have found this technique useful when intercepting touch events on complex views (i.e. those with several subviews) where I don't have access to the sourcecode to the views, and therefore can't hack/modify their behaviour.